# Create swift framework with shown Interfaces, cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm creating my swift cocoa touch framework and I want to display classes, methods and declarations without the code implementation.

When Generate my framework I don't see my classes I only see a header file containing only a ProjectNameSwift.h class.
How can we do that ?
I wondered if we can use Xcode generated interfaces in our framework... bu I do not find a way...

Creating my cocoa touch framework, trying to hide code implementation without hiding classes and methods declaration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide source code in swift framework when distributing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989818/hide-source-code-in-swift-framework-when-distributing)

Comment: I do not see classes when I generate my framework