# How to build iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk

I want to write a iOS SDK. But I am stuck with the process in which category I need to create it under Frameworks & Library like Framework, Static Library & Metal Library and why?

Queries:-
Suppose I create under Framework then how can I deliver it to the client. I mean what is the build process so I can bundled it into a single file?
Which language will be better for the SDK Development (Obj-c OR Swift) and why?

Comment: Check this tutorial it really helped me out! https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: @SanadBarjawi Yes, I have checked it and want to know after create a framework I need to share it with client. So, I want to share the single file only not the whole file, means don't want to give the acess of the source code. How it's possible?

Comment: single file? just upload that specific file to oneDrive, dropbox, email instead

Comment: No, it doesn't mean like this. I mean to say after create a project under Framework then adding some Swift files then  I don't want to deliver the whole files with client.
Or in other words somehow he should not be able to see the source code.

Comment: If it's not possible then he can see the code and edit also according his requirement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989818/hide-source-code-in-swift-framework-when-distributing check this, if it helped upvote

Comment: Thanks @SanadBarjawi. I will check it. After creation the framework I am unable to access the Swift files into my testing app. Do you have any idea of that?

Comment: try accessing the ..xcworkspace instead of the normal .xcodeprej

Answer (score 1):

> OS X makes extensive use of frameworks to distribute shared code and
>   resources, such as the interfaces to the system itself. You can create
>   frameworks of your own to provide shared code and resources to one or
>   more of your company’s applications. You can also create frameworks
>   containing class libraries or add-on modules with the intention of
>   distributing them to other developers.
>
> The information in this document provides the background you need to
>   create frameworks and the steps needed to create them in Xcode.
>   Although creating frameworks is not difficult, there are some
>   guidelines you should follow when doing so. Xcode simplifies the
>   creation process by helping you create the framework bundle and manage
>   the information and placement of files in that bundle. However, this
>   document also provides additional information about how to perform
>   many less obvious tasks. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html)

There is an guide on Stackoverflow which will help you to create a framework with Swift - "[How Do I Create a Development Framework In iOS Including Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816507/how-do-i-create-a-development-framework-in-ios-including-swift)"

Comment: After building the SDK, I am getting an error:
"Could not find module for target 'arm64-apple-ios'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64" and then  Icreate the FAT file through lipo command but after that also I am getting the same error.